# Looking for item in array

Tags: arrays, indexing

First: I cannot use the Arrays package; request from our teacher. I looked through the site and it seems a lot of the solutions proposed involve that package.

My question is:

I have an array full of objects of type Object and I need to use a method to find a specific item in that array and return the array index. It returns -1 if nothing is found.

The method I created is as follows

```
    public int find(Object item) { 
    int isFind = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item)
            isFind = i;
    } return isFind;
```

When I run using arrayofObjects.find((Object)userInput), I always get an exception at this line:

```
if (array[i] == item)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the input.

Code for initializing an empty array

```
private Object array[];
ContainerVer1(int size){
    array = new Object[size];
    for  (int i = 0; i <=(size-1); i++) {
        array[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Code for adding an object to the array, if the cell is empty

```
public boolean add(Object item) {
    boolean hasSpace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
        array[i] = item;
        hasSpace = true;
        break;
        } else hasSpace = false;
    } return hasSpace;
```

For an array with a size of 5, I ask for user Inputs, like so

```
ContainerVer1 arrayofStrings = new ContainerVer1(5);


    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string or 'DONE' to finish");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = sc.next();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        if (userInput.equals("DONE") == false)
        arrayofStrings.add(userInput);
        count++;


    } while (userInput.equals("DONE") == false && count <=4);
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: What does the exception say?  What is in the array?  Your comparison of objects (Object references) probably is not working the way you expect, but without more info I don't think you are going to get much help on this one.  Also tag your answer with the language (Java, I assume).

Comment: you might have to cast the object as the type of the element in array

Comment: Also check your indexing, should probably be "i < array.length" not "i <= array.length".

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the "exception" error but it seems the method has an error. The array contains inputs from the user. The array type is Object. When I invoke the method arrayofObjects.find((Object)userInput3), I still get -1 (as if userInput3 is not in the array, even if the userInput3 is "apple" and the array contains "apple" in one of the cells.

Comment: You will probably need to show more code - how is apple initialized, how is it inserted into the array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array[i] == (int)item) // if array is of type int []
```

C# syntax btw, should be similar in Java too

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here:

1)  The indexing was off by 1 (change <= to <).

2)  The comparison is looking at whether the two variables are pointing to the exact same object, not whether strings are the same sequence of characters.  If you do the following in your do/while loop:

```
arrayofStrings.add(userInput);
int index = arrayofStrings.find(userInput);
System.out.printf("object index: %d\n", index);
```

Then the comparison will work, because you are checking whether the object you just added exists in the array.  On the other hand, if you check for the following:

```
arrayofStrings.add(userInput);
int index2 = arrayofStrings.find("TEST");
System.out.printf("string index: %d\n", index2);
```

Then the comparison will fail because even though the strings are the same, the underlying objects are different (a new one was created by passing in "TEST").  The find function does not know that it is comparing Strings.  One way of modifying find function would be to check if the item and array[i] are "instanceof" Strings and utilize the "compareTo" function of String to check for equality.